# How to add a property to the property view of "SCA Composite Designer" tool

Tags: properties, eclipse-plugin, soa, composite, sca

I am using the SCA Composite Designer eclipse plugin, to design systems that follow SCA component model. 
At some point, I needed an additional property for the component element. I need the additional property to appear in the property view. The figure below shows the tool with the property view for the component.

[image]

As you can see, the property view in the figure shows some properties for the "Calculator" component selected. My target is to add an additional property called "path" to this property view.
I was able to add the property to the XML file of the diagram. However, this is not enough for me. As I mentioned, I need the additional property to appear and to be possibly modified in the property view.

My question is: Is there a way to simply add the additional property to the property view? Or do I have to modify the source code of the tool (which will be painful)? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since SCA Composites are simply XML files, you can always open the XML file and add the property yourself using the element `<property>`

http://docs.oasis-open.org/opencsa/sca-assembly/sca-assembly-1.1-spec-csd07.html#_Toc270599541

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. First, I do not want to add a property element to the component. I rather want to add a property to the component element, which is a different thing. For example, I do not want to add a property tag like this <property name="something"> , rather an example for what I want is <component name="something" additional_property="something_else">. Here, the additional_property is what I need. Second, I mentioned in my question that I know I can achieve this using the XML file, but I want to add the property to the properties view.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem, now I get what your problem is. I don't know STP at all so my help here is useless, but my gut feeling is that what you're trying to do is not possible for one reason: To me, STP Composite editor looks like is created using EMF and GMF, both models use a XSD to create the underlying model of SCA. Since the model to create the UI is highly tied to those XSDs, your modification in the XML, in this case an attribute in the SCA element, will not be recognized. It may even throw/show an error in the UI, perhaps Problem or Errors views.